# Decent FREE Web Based FTP Alternatives?

Tags: web-applications, file-manager

Like the subject mentions, I'm looking for a free FTP Alternative that's web based. What I need is the ability to grant people like our marketing team the ability to upload marketing images and instantly have those images show up in `ourdomain.com/images/newimage.jpg`. I have found plenty of excellent file sharing programs that are essentially drop box and sharepoint alternatives but have yet to find an FTP Alternative. Also ideally multiple account authentication would be great.

If anyone is familiar with cPanel I'm essentially looking for their File Manager or something very similar to it (obviously stand alone and preferably free).

Does anybody know if anything like this exists?

Comment: My suggestion is to be very careful with free web based FTP clients.  

You are going to be giving your FTP login details to someone...somewhere...are you comfortable doing that?  

I wouldn't be.

For example, I just found this http://www.net2ftp.com/ - it doesn't even use SSL!!!  Crazy

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ourwebftp.com/

They have a free non-commercial use or a $39 license.

http://www.ourwebftp.com/dl.php is the download page for those!

Good luck and I hope this helps you.

Before you spend time here is the feature's list:

```
FLEXIBLE FILE LISTING

Filter file listing with wildcards
Split file listing in pages
Sort files by name, size and date
SECURITY AND CONVENIENCE

FTP usernames and passwords are stored in encrypted session files - no HTML hidden fields with plaintext username and password
Administrator control panel allows to set up your server address and action permissions
FILE MANAGEMENT

Rename, delete, move, and copy files
Create and rename directories
Create and edit text, html, php, css files
Chmod files and directories
VARIOUS OPTIONS TO GET FILES

Download files to your computer
Zip on-the-fly and download several files at once
Send files to emails
QUICK UPLOAD OF MULTIPLE FILES

Upload and extract on-the-fly zip compressed files
Upload files from another FTP server
Transload (get a file from remote URL and upload to your FTP server bypassing your local machine)
```